# How do I make classes talk to each other?

Tags: python, wxpython

Here is the situation

```
class App(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent,id=-1,title='Test App'):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,id,title,size=((1050,690)))

        self.mode = 'Test'


class SetModes:
    def __init__(self):
        self.GetModes = App(None,-1)

        self.appmode = ''

    def SetMode(self):
        self.appmode = self.GetModes.mode
```

Now this is just an example script because I already know this won't work but it shows what im essentially trying to do. Let me clarify:

I want to get and set some variables from the app class. I want to be able to do this from my 'SetModes' class. Problem is I can't make a instance of it because I can't assign a parent to the instance so the self.GetModes method doesn't work, It tells me either the instance can't 'NOT' have a parent, So does this mean I can't create an instance of my App Class if all I want to do is use some of it's variables and functions??.

So How do I get this to work. Can I have a class communicate with a class that requires a parent?

Answer (score 1):

I think part of your problem is that frames need to be initialized from inside a `wx.App` instance  and then the `MainLoop()` must be called (see [this tutorial](http://wiki.wxpython.org/Using%20wxPython%20Demo%20Code). Note how the frame has a parent `None`).

After that, a solution like jdi's will work. However, I still don't like using references if I can avoid it. For a parent calling functions on an immediate child, it's ok but my own personal rule is that my classes cannot see any objects they do not directly own (i.e. no knowledge about children of children).

I'm a big fan of [PubSub](http://wiki.wxpython.org/WxLibPubSub) for communicating between unrelated classes. Unlike `wx.Event` objects, there is no need for any heirarchical relationship. Unlike the reference solution put forth by jdi, there is no need for classes to have any knowledge at all about each other's structures.

What it comes down to is, in your application, can a `SetModes` instance ever exist *without* an `App` instance? If no, can you maybe incorporate `SetModes`' logic into `App`? If yes, then coding `SetModes` to explicitly deal with `App` is bad design.

Using `PubSub`, you send a request message from `SetModes`. `App` sees the message and can then send a response message, which is seen by `SetModes`. Completely separate, completely asynchronous. `SetModes` doesn't need to know anything about `App`, just the message formats.

Answer (score 0):

Just because the wx.Frame requires a parent, doesn't mean you can't assign a reference to it in another unassociated class. Just parent your App instance to something as you would do normally, but pass the reference over to your SetModes:

```
app = App(parent)
setModes = SetModes()
setModes.GetModes = app
```

This comes down to a design issue with your program. Widgets need parents.

Comment: I concede it's a design issue. But I'm kind of confused by this. I see you assign the App class to the variable 'app' but how does that work when my app class requires a parent. If you could we work my code to fit what your suggesting I would much appreciate it. Seeing my code corrected will help me for future reference.

Comment: I would check out the other answer. Mine was a bit general since I have no idea about what the intention of you code is.